# Responsive Web Design on huge screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How do people deal with phone screen sizes such as QHD or FHD? 
Is there a legit tutorial on how to use `@media` on these situations?

When using `@media(max-width:768px)` it appears fine on phones with low res, but , e.g., on a Galaxy S9 which supports resolutions up to 2960x1440px, the website looks like the desktop version.

Comment: You can set media queries at any pixel width. If you expect a site to be shown at those resolutions (like if you have a dashboard designed to be shown on a TV), go for it.

Comment: Take a look at this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/. You can google for media queries for high resolution devices